# Array unique and count in multidimensional ararys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Anyone know how to reach $wanted_array given the $initial_array dynamically?
Thanks!

```
// $initial_array

Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [thingy] => 4
        [date] => 27/11/2013
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [thingy] => 4
        [date] => 27/11/2013
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [thingy] => 2
        [date] => 27/11/2015
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [thingy] => 2
        [date] => 27/11/2015
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [thingy] => 2
        [date] => 27/11/2015
    )
)

// $wanted_array
// The quantity key will count instances that array item in $initial_array

Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [thingy] => 4
        [date] => 27/11/2013
        [quantity] = 2
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [thingy] => 2
        [date] => 27/11/2015
        [quantity] = 3
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, for some reason I couldn't edit my own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've broken this down into two steps.

1. Arranging data according to dates and storing the result in $result variable.

   ```
   $result   = array();
   foreach($array as $arr) {
      $result[$arr['date']][] =  $arr;
   }
   ```

This gives:

```
  Array
   (
     [27/11/2013] => Array
      (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [thingy] => 4
                [date] => 27/11/2013
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [thingy] => 4
                [date] => 27/11/2013
            )

    )

[27/11/2015] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [thingy] => 2
                [date] => 27/11/2015
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [thingy] => 2
                [date] => 27/11/2015
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [thingy] => 2
                [date] => 27/11/2015
            )

    )

   )
```

2. Looping through the array and formatting it as per our needs. Note that the  sub array length indicates the quantity.

   ```
   foreach($result as $res) {
      $final[] = array_merge(
         current($res), 
         array("quantity" => count($res))
      );
    }
   ```

Output:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [thingy] => 4
        [date] => 27/11/2013
        [quantity] => 2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [thingy] => 2
        [date] => 27/11/2015
        [quantity] => 3
    )

)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.
Did you notice the quantity part, though?

Comment: You're welcome. Please up vote the answer and accept it if it solves your purpose. Thanks! :)

Comment: Okay, I'll take a look right away. Looks like I missed something out.

Comment: Please check out my updated answer. This will certainly resolve your issue. :)